# what is the difference between angular.element and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, getelementbyid

`Angularjs` get element by id : You can use the `angular.element(‘#element_id’);` to get the element by id where `#element_id` is id of element.

Here is an alternative of javascript `document.getElementById` in angularjs –

Angularjs get element by id:

```
var currentElement = angular.element('#element_id');
```

But what is the difference between **angular.element** and  **document.getElementById**

Comment: thanks, but what's the best I can use in angular App and why ?

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40429365/2545680) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add to the **@evolutionxbox** answer, that `document.getElementById` should probably be slightly faster than `angular.element`, since it doensn't have to go through the routine of figuring out what is passed into the function and what steps should be taken based on that.

Regarding what should be used when. Since these two methods return different object types (jquery vs HTMLElement), you can select the method based on either the standard practice in your application - whether to use jquery elements or native dom elements for manipulation, or on what operations you're going to perform on them as some operations are easier to do with jquery object than with native HTMLElement.

For example, if you want to use any jquery method, like `.hasClass()` you need to wrap element like this `angular.element(document.getElementById('some')).hasClass()`, so it's easier to just go with `angular.element('#some').hasClass();` in the first place.

Generally, I would go with `angular.element` approach as it's preferred method inside angular's native directives.

Comment: Thank you Maximus but for angular.element is that it has advantages over document.getElementById ?

Comment: adding to what I've written, if you want to use any jquery method, like `.hasClass()` you need to wrap element like this `angular.element(document.getElementById('some')).hasClass()`, so it's easier to just go with `angular.element('#some').hasClass();`

Comment: @MohammedAkdim, you can also accept my answer if you feel it fully answers your question

Comment: you said document.getElementById should probably be slightly faster than angular.element but why AngularJS the community adding angular.element ??

And is it possible to use both(document.getElementById & angular.element) in a project AngularJS ?

Comment: because it's a `slightly faster speed vs greater convenience` choice, and angular team opted for the latter. And I would too. yes, it's certainly possible to use both in your app, but that would create incostistency

Comment: @MohammedAkdim, you're welcome, consider accepting the answer then

Answer (score 4):

When you select an object with an ID using angular.element (or jQuery), it takes a shortcut and uses `document.getElementById`.

The biggest difference is that [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) alias, and returns a jQuery (or jQuery lite) object.

Whereas [`document.getElementById` is a native DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), which returns an [HTMLElement object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

---

#### tl:dr;

**Always read the documentation**

Comment: (anyone who wants to downvote, please leave a comment)

Comment: Thank you very much